# Cannot add to Vuex store correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have this Vuex 2 store:

```
const datastore = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {          
    socketcluster: {
      connection: false,
      channels: []
    },
    selected_offers: []
  },
  mutations: {
    addOffer: function(offer) {
      datastore.state.selected_offers.push(offer) // first problem: cannot just use state.offers as it throws an undefined
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getOffers: function(){
      return datastore.state.selected_offers; 
    }
  }
});
```

And inside a Vue 2 component I do:

```
  methods: {
    clicked: function(){
      console.log("Toggle Offer");
      if ( datastore.getters.getOffers.filter(function(o){ o.id == this.offer.id } ).length == 0 ) {
        // add it
        datastore.commit('addOffer', this.offer)
      } else {
        // TODO remove it
      }
    }
}
```

What happens is that when I trigger the method, the store changes as follows:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter passed to a mutation is the `state` object. So, you're pushing the entire `state` object to the `selected_offers` array.

Your mutation method should look like this:

```
mutations: {
  addOffer: function(state, offer) {
    state.selected_offers.push(offer)
  }
},
```

Here's the [documentation for vuex mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html).

Comment: Awesome. Don't know how I even missed that. Guess I never looked at the parameters actually.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple way to work with vuex pattern, In big applications you should use actions instead of mutating the state directly from the component "like I did ", if so i urge you to read more about vuex.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {          
    socketcluster: {
      connection: false,
      channels: []
    },
    selected_offers: [ "offer1", "offer2"]
  },
  mutations: {
    addOffer: function( state, offer ) {
      state.selected_offers.push(offer);
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getOffers: function( state ){
      return state.selected_offers; 
    }
  }
});

new Vue({ 
    store,
    data: function() {
      return {
          offer: "offer3"
      }
    },
    methods: {
      clicked: function() {
        if ( this.offers.length === 2 ) {
            this.$store.commit('addOffer', this.offer)
        } else {
          // TODO remove it
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
        offers: function() {
            return this.$store.getters.getOffers;
        }
    }
}).$mount( "#app" );
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.3.1/vuex.js"></script>


<div id="app">
    <div v-for="offer in offers" > {{offer}}</div>
    <button @click="clicked"> clicked </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not mutate state from the component, but had a component method call a store mutation.

Comment: Yes, we both talk about the same thing. Sorry I wasn't clear enough, what I meant is instead of committing the mutation in the component it would be better if the component dispatches an action. and the action itself commits the mutation. And one more thing, once you register your store in the global Vue instance it will be reachable under this.$store in all the other components.